# Custom work item field for multiple templates in TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

We have a requirement of introducing a new work item field (say, Product Version) in TFS and that can be used in both "Bug" and "Task" templates.
This field should have 4 allowed values  (i.e., version 1.1, version 1.5, version 1.7, version 2.0).

I could achieve this through Process template editor, but for that, I had to add two different fields and with different names (for example, Product Version_Task, and Product Version_Bug).

This serves the purpose, but this increases maintenance, as it will be a repetitive effort to add/ remove future versions. Also, due to this, querying TFS work items seems a little less user friendly (due to the field names).

How can we achieve having a single field and to use it in multiple work item templates?

Also, I would be more interested in knowing UI rather than witadmin commands. But still, any solution is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you believe that you have to add two fields. All fields in TFS are server fields and can be added to any work item.

If you add a single field to PBI and copy it verbatim to bug you can add it to both. If you have trouble then you have not copied the field exactly.

Additionally you can use a Global List to maintain a single set of values to be used in every type.